# Profiling MATLAB mex CUDA applications with the NVIDIA visual profiler

Tags: matlab, cuda, mex

I am trying to profile a CUDA code that is embedded in a mex file, called from MATLAB. Running on a win7 x64 machine, MATLAB r2014b

The code is structured as follows:

```
 MATLAB   test.m
    ->contains some standard code generating variables (and calling 1 or 2 minor own MATLAB fucntions)
    -> calls testcuda.mex
        ->contains small, standard, no library C++ code
        -> calls either test1.cu or test2.cu
              ->.cu files end in cudaDeviceReset();
```

I did the following, as stated in [several places](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/520355/visual-profiler-for-matlab-code-unable-to-collect-results-33-/) on the internet:

1. Compiled mex files. Test them. They work.
2. Add `exit` in the end of test.m.
3. Launch the NVIDIA Visual Profiler. File -> New Session.
4. add the full path of the Matlab executable file, for example `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\matlab.exe`
5. Working directory: add the full path of the Matlab .m file. `C:\CUDA_MATLABtests\MyToolbox`
6. Arguments: `-nojvm -nosplash -r test`

However, when I run the profiler,I get

```
======== Warning: No CUDA application was profiled, exiting
```

And nothing more.

I am missing some instruction?

Is there any particular code structure that would make the profiler not to profile?

Comment: I think in step 4 you have to use `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\matlab.exe`. Alternatively try to use the `-wait` option.

Comment: @Daniel indeed.... win64 folder, what a silly mistake. Being MATLAB already in Program Files and not in Program Files x86 I thought it was already the 64 bit version. Considern answering this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Matlab installation comes with two binaries, a launcher in `<matlabroot>\bin` and the main application in `<matlabroot>\bin\<arch>`. The later is the executable which also executes the mex functions in it's address space.

- When a debugging tool needs to start the application directly, you have to start the one in `<matlabroot>\bin\<arch>`.
- When a debugging tool automatically attaches to child processes as well, it is typically sufficient to start the binary in `<matlabroot>\bin` setting the `-wait` parameter. Seeing the launcher application terminating, debugging tools often stop.

Never use the binary in `<matlabroot>\bin\<arch>` directly unless you have to.